# convert a select option to boolean value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning angular2. Here I have the following Problem:

I have a `select` field which should work as a boolean value:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="caseSensitive">
    <option>false</option>
     <option>true</option>
   </select>
```

No if i use it in my Filter it will send as a string not as a boolean. Is it possible to convert it using a converter or something like that:

Here my complete HTML code:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="nameFilter"/>
<select [(ngModel)]="caseSensitive">
    <option>false</option>
     <option>true</option>
   </select>



<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let p of (persons | MyFilter: nameFilter:caseSensitive); let i = index">
    <td>{{i + 1 }} </td>
    <td>{{
      p.givenName+" "+ p.familyName
    }}</td>
    <td><img src="/img/flags/{{ p.nationality}}.png"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

The ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {MyFilter} from './MyFilter';

@Component({
  selector: 'pizza-root',
  pipes: [MyFilter],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'  
})
export class AppComponent {
    public year = new Date().getFullYear();
    public persons =[{"givenName":"Paul", "familyName": "Smith", "nationality":"american"},
                     {"givenName":"Jens", "familyName":"myName1", "nationality":"german"},
                     {"givenName":"Ernst", "familyName":"myName1", "nationality":"german"},
                     {"givenName":"Jenny", "familyName":"myName1", "nationality":"german"}];
    constructor (){
        console.log(this.persons);
    }
}
```

The Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'MyFilter'
})

export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform{
    transform( items: any[], args: string, caseSensitive : boolean ):any {
        if (items != null && args != undefined && args  != ''){
            if (caseSensitive){ 
                console.log("caseSensitive")
                return items.filter(item=>item.givenName.indexOf(args)!== -1);
            } else {
                console.log("caseInSensitive")
                return items.filter(item=> item.givenName.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase())!== -1);
            }
        }
        console.log("else")
        return items;
    }

}
```

The Problem is, that the pipe not working correctly because `caseSensitive` is the bind as a string not as a boolean value.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The values in `<option>` are strings or they are stringified if other types are provided. If you use `ngValue` instead, you can use other types and `ngModel` retains the type.

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="caseSensitive">
    <option [ngValue]="false">false</option>
     <option [ngValue]="true">true</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: [value] property binding always behave like a string, so it is different from  [ngValue]

Comment: Right `[value]` just binds to the `<option>` `value` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option which handles only string values. `ngValue` is an Angular directive that handles any value type.